# Programmatically create a 2*2 and 2*1 grid view in iphone

Tags: iphone, gridview

Currently i am referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862531/how-to-create-grid-button-on-iphone-10-10-matrix) and am able to create a 2*2 grid view

```
int rows = 2;
int cols = 2;

float gridWidth = 1024.0;
float gridHeight = 1024.0;

float buttonWidth = 100.0;
float buttonHeight = 100.0;

// float gapHorizontal = (gridWidth - (buttonWidth * rows)) / (rows + 1);
// float gapVertical = (gridHeight - (buttonHeight * cols)) / (cols + 1);

float gapHorizontal = 40;
float gapVertical = 40;

float offsetX;
float offsetY;

int count = 0;

do {
    offsetX = gapHorizontal + ((count % rows) * (buttonWidth + gapHorizontal));
    offsetY = gapVertical + ((count / rows) * (buttonHeight + gapVertical));

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offsetX, offsetY,  buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [self.view addSubview:view];


    offsetX+= buttonWidth + gapHorizontal;

    count++;

} while(count < rows * cols);
```

But when I am try to create a 2*1 grid view

By changing this to

```
int rows = 2;
int cols = 1;
```

I'm not able to do so. Its only creating 2 views.

Is there any simple solution available for this?

Comment: Steps through on the debugger and check each of the values in each variable as you go through.  You should be able to spot where there is a problem.

Comment: I found my solution by following this SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782499/creating-a-new-row-of-uibutton-programatically/9782670#9782670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is the expected behavior. Two rows with one column is exactly two cells, or its representation views.

Comment: So i want to create 2 views in first row and the single view in below row, how can i do this?

Comment: If you want to use this code, call it twice. Once with `rows=2;cols=1;` and once with `rows=1;cols=1;`. You can adjust the initial offsets to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Is there any simple solution alternative to above code is available?

Comment: Of course. You want me to do the work for you? You need to at least first accept the answer.